# Linear map on a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field $F$ of finite characteristic $p$. Let $\alpha: V\longrightarrow V$ be a linear operator on $V$, and suppose that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that for all $v\in V$, $\alpha^n(v)=v$, while for each positive integer $i<n$ there exists $v_i\in V$ such that $\alpha^i(v_i)\neq v_i$. I have proved that if $n$ is not divisible by $p$ then $\alpha$ is diagonalizable.

> Prove that $\alpha$ is diagonalizable if and only  if $n$ is not divisible by $p$.

Dear Professors,

I am a 1st year student preparing for Qualifying exam. I am quite sorry that I post such questions but I really need to pass the exam of such questions if I want to continue my PhD. I will be very grateful for your tolerance and be more grateful if you give a help.

Comment: Could you provide a little context, and perhaps your thoughts on the problem? It's rather boring to just attempt a problem without any insight into why it might be interesting

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting the answer doesn't make it invisible!

Comment: @DerekHolt They are visible only for users rated 10k+.

Comment: Also, I believe the majority of people here are not really professors. I'm quite far from it, myself.

Answer (score 2):

If $\gcd(n,p)=1$, then $X^n-1$ has no multiple roots. Let $m_{\alpha}\in F[X]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Then $m_{\alpha}\mid X^n-1$, and therefore $m_{\alpha}$ has also no multiple roots, so $\alpha$ is diagonalizable.

Conversely, let's assume that $\alpha$ is diagonalizable and $\lambda_i\in F$ are its eigenvalues. Since $\alpha^n=\hbox{id}_V$ we have $\lambda_i^n=1$. If $p\mid n$, then write $n=pm$ and notice that $\lambda_i^m=1$, so $\alpha^m=\hbox{id}_V$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of getting you started. I'm not saying that this is the best way - just a very concrete way.

Let's do the case $n=2$. So $p>2$, and $1/2\in F$. If $v$ is any vector, you can write it as a sum
$$
v=\frac12(v+\alpha(v))+\frac12(v-\alpha(v)).
$$
Show that above we have written $v$ as a sum of two eigenvectors of $\alpha$. Why does the claim follow from this?

If $n=3$, let $\omega\in F$ be a primitive cubic root of unity. Why does that such an element exist? In that case you can do the same with
$$
v=\frac13(v+\alpha(v)+\alpha^2(v))+\frac13(v+\omega\alpha(v)+\omega^2\alpha^2(v))+\frac13(v+\omega^2\alpha(v)+\omega\alpha^2(v))
$$
instead.

Generalize, or think of another, less computational way.